# Order table by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine that I have a table with entities and some of them have forks; the column fork stores the id of the parent entry or 0, if that entry doesn't have a fork.

Table ents:

```
id  name        fork
1   Adidas      0
2   Betina      0
3   Shop Adidas 1
4   Shell       0
5   StoreAdidas 1
6   Shell 1     4
```

This is how I would like to get the results, i.e., sorted by name but with the forks next to its parent:

```
id  name
1   Adidas
3   Shop Adidas
5   StoreAdidas
2   Betina
4   Shell
6   Shell 1
```

Is this possible with a MySQL query?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @LongMKNguyễn Nothing is being concatenated.

Comment: It would be advisable to have forks in their own table rather than in the same with their "parent" entry, as the rules of database normalization require: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM nameofTable AS t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.fork <> 0 THEN t.fork ELSE t.id END, 
         CASE WHEN t.fork <> 0 THEN t.id ELSE 0 END
```

Explanation:
The Statement is simply sorting by two column:
fork and id. However, some conditioning has been added so that we only sort by fork if one exits for the given row otherwise the id is to be used. Meaning they are shown directly next to "parent" entry. Multiple forks (aka. "children") are then again ordered by their id.

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u86AL9nMLNHkzoqRkXMaae/0).

Comment: thank you, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by name instead of by id, a self-join is needed:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from table_name t1 left join table_name t2
on t1.fork = t2.id
order by coalesce(t2.name, t1.name)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88a8ce9ca5517b1a5dd9a6cb2de9b263)

Comment: Thank you, this answer is also correct, if sorting by name is needed.